# Fail to run Celery tutorial

Tags: python, celery

Here is the tasks.py

```
from celery.task import task

@task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Here is the celeryconfig.py

```
print 'importing ' + __file__
BROKER_URL = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("tasks", )
```

Here is the file that i run. 
tasks.py:

```
from tasks import add
result = add.delay(4, 4)
print result.wait()
```

The program just stuck in the wait method.

Celeryd prints the following error:

```
Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
Please see http://bit.ly/gLye1c for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
{'retries': 0, 'task': 'tasks.add', 'args': (4, 4), 'expires': None, 'eta': None
, 'kwargs': {}, 'id': '8c973638-4a87-4afa-8a78-958153066215'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python26\lib\site-packages\celery-2.4.5-py2.6.egg\celery\worker\consu
mer.py", line 427, in receive_message
    eventer=self.event_dispatcher)
  File "d:\python26\lib\site-packages\celery-2.4.5-py2.6.egg\celery\worker\job.p
y", line 297, in from_message
    on_ack=on_ack, delivery_info=delivery_info, **kw)
  File "d:\python26\lib\site-packages\celery-2.4.5-py2.6.egg\celery\worker\job.p
y", line 261, in __init__
    self.task = registry.tasks[self.task_name]
  File "d:\python26\lib\site-packages\celery-2.4.5-py2.6.egg\celery\registry.py"
, line 66, in __getitem__
    raise self.NotRegistered(key)
NotRegistered: 'tasks.add'
```

When I run celeryd.py status, I the tasks.add is not here.

```
D:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\celery-2.4.5-py2.6.egg\celery\bin>celeryctl.py in
pect registered
<- registered
-> onfirenbpc: OK
    * celery.backend_cleanup
    * celery.chord
    * celery.chord_unlock
    * celery.ping
```

I run on windows, and linux as well. There are the same problem.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set you `add` method as task? One of variant to do that would use decorator:

```
from celery.decorators import task

@task
def add():
    pass
```

Comment: from celery.task import task

@task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

Comment: I added the decoration. In fact, I just copied the file from the tutorial.